# WSS 3.0 Backup/Restore Root Site Collection to Sub-Site of New Site Collection

Tags: backup, sharepoint, restore, wss

Our intranet was originally setup to be at the root of its site collection. We are trying to change this so that our new internet site will live in the root and the intranet will be a sub-site.

At this point I have created a new web application and site collection to house the internet and intranet. I used the 'stsadm -o backup' command to create a backup of our current intranet. I then ran the 'stsadm -o restore' command to restore the intranet site collection to wss/sites/intranet. This seems to have worked as I am able to access the intranet from this location.

The issue I now seem to have is that images, sub-sites, etc. are all making reference as if the intranet is still the root site. So for example a link to a sub-site is pointing to wss/department/technology/default.aspx and it needs to point to wss/sites/intranet/department/technology/default.aspx.

I am looking for help and/or clarification on two things:
   1. Am I approaching the migration of a root site collection to a sub-site the best way?
   2. How would I go about updating the link references so that they are based on the intranet now being a sub-site instead of the root site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you share a little more information on why you are wanting to subordinate the existing root site collection to a new site collection in its place? Internet and Intranet sites typically have different audiences, and putting content in a place where authenticated and unauthenticated users will both have access is asking for accidental information disclosure as I have yet to see a SharePoint installation where people didn't screw up permissions and inheritance.  Also, as you are finding, you are going to have to (manually) update a ton of links.

I would think the process would be much easier using alternate access mappings, separate web applications, and links than it would be to move the whole site collection.

intranet.domain.com --> existing web app and site collection

internet.domain.com --> new web app and separate root site collection. (you can provide a link to the intranet from the internet site if needed for some reason)

Comment: Basically we want to allow certain people to have access to the intranet through the internet site. Anyone in the company can access the intranet when on our network but we want to limit who can get in from outside.

From what you mentioned, do you think we could leave them separate and when a user authenticates on the internet, we could display a link that points to the intranet? Would they have to authenticate again when hitting the intranet?

Comment: Absolutely!  Take a look at the two following sample architectures for ideas on how to set it up: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835621.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262582.aspx.  The Visio diagrams included with the article will be very helpful in understanding how to do it visually.

Comment: I am hoping you can provide one more piece of insight. I cannot seem to find this in the links you provided or maybe I am just not piecing things together right.

When a user access the internet site from outside our network they can access it and login fine. When they click the link to go to the intranet, they are prompted to login again. Which lets them in, but is it possible to pass authentication between site collections on different web apps? These sites are on the same physical server and both using NTFS authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use STSADM Import/Export instead of BackUp/Restore or better to use some third party tools. I am still not clear about how can you back up  a site collection and restore it as a subsite ? It would be possible if you restore it as another site collection. BackUp/Restore doesnt update the GUIDs and the references, it just creates the exact dump of the contents, so try to use Export/Import and Import it as another site collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can move a site between site collections using stsadm -o export to dump the site, then stsadm -o import to import into your new site collection - this is applicable to the root site as any other site.

You can then use [Sharepoint URL Redirector](http://rdacollaboration.codeplex.com/releases/view/28073) to redirect traffic to the new URL.

Comment: Does the URL Redirector take into account people programmatically accessing things via WEBDAV (e.g. //mysharepointsite/doclibrary/ --> redirect to new //myNEWsharepointsite/doclibrary/)?

Comment: Interesting question, to which I don't have the answer yet.